# TCL - Extract line from text file to TCL Script

Tags: text, input, tcl, extract

Well, i tried to find online my answer but actually I didn't and I really need help..

- I have a **text file** (file.txt) that contain :

> ```
>  C:/Users/00_file/toto.odb,
>  dis,455,
>  stre,54,
>  stra,25,
>  C:/Users/00_file/tota.odb,
> ```

- And a TCL script that allows me to read *values* of each lines :

> ```
> set Infile [open "C:/Users/00_file/file.txt" r]
> set filelines [split $Infile ","] 
> set Namepath [lindex $filelines 1 0]   #*doesn't work*
> set dis [lindex $filelines 2 0]        # *work good*
> ...
> ```

The problem is when I want the complete line 1 of the text file with my TCL script, some informations are missing and extra caracter disapear..

How can I have the complete string (line 1 of my text file) ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you pls. improve your question? 1) `file.txt` happens to contain a number of lines, but your use of `split` breaks the content separated by commas (",") not by newline characters ("\n"). 2) What is a "complete line" in your wording? You should at least document the excerpt from `file.txt` in a way that matches your expectations (not what you are seeing, actually).

Answer (score 1):

You open the file for reading but you don't actually read from it. $Infile is just (basically) a pointer to a file descriptor, not the contents of the file:

```
% set fh [open file.txt r]
% puts $fh
file3
```

The idiomatic way to read from a file: line-by-line

```
set fh [open "C:/Users/00_file/file.txt" r]
set data [list]
while {[get $fh line] != -1} {
    lappend data [split $line ,]
}
close $fh
```

Or, read the whole file and split it on newlines

```
set fh [open "C:/Users/00_file/file.txt" r]
set data [lmap line [split [read -nonewline $fh] \n] {split $line ,}]
close $fh
```

Then access the data

```
set Namepath [lindex $data 0 0]   ;# first line, first field 
set dis [lindex $data 1 1]        ;# second line, second field
```

Answer (score 0):

Tcl code will be as follow:

```html
   set file [open c:/filename.txt ]
    set file_device [read  $file]
    set data [split $file_device "\n"]

    for {set count 0} {$count < 2} {incr count} {
        
    puts $data
        
        # for every iterartion one line will be printed.
     # split /n is use for getting the end of each line.
        # open command open the file at given path. 
        # read command is use to read the open file.
    }
    close $file
    break
```

this will take the line one after another.